# MySQL count query takes too long for particular table only

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, innodb

I have one table that contains documents, and on production there are about 1.2 millon records in this table. On this table when I do `select count(*) from <table>`, it takes too long that at the end I need to restart the DB. On the other hand I also have many other table containing 10-12 million rows but those tables does not have this issue.

These are indexes of that table

```
mysql> show index from candidates_resume\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: candidates_resume
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 843657
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
      Visible: YES
   Expression: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: candidates_resume
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: candidate_id
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: candidate_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 844009
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
      Visible: YES
   Expression: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
        Table: candidates_resume
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: candidates_resume_uploaded_on_e4c78158b8c18f_uniq
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: uploaded_on
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 844009
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
      Visible: YES
   Expression: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
        Table: candidates_resume
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: candidates_resume_pdf_file_5b052603240d1d43_uniq
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: pdf_file
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 844009
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
      Visible: YES
   Expression: NULL
*************************** 5. row ***************************
        Table: candidates_resume
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: candidates_resume_watermark_file_68fd6000f27d4f8d_uniq
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: watermark_file
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 844009
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
      Visible: YES
   Expression: NULL
```

And this is result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `candidates_resume` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `uploaded_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `candidate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `pdf_file` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resume_text` longtext NOT NULL,
  `watermark_file` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `html_file` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `candidate_id` (`candidate_id`),
  KEY `candidates_resume_uploaded_on_e4c78158b8c18f_uniq` (`uploaded_on`),
  KEY `candidates_resume_pdf_file_88ec1f31_uniq` (`pdf_file`),
  KEY `candidates_resume_watermark_file_23af2d43_uniq` (`watermark_file`),
  CONSTRAINT `candidate_id_refs_id_88f99c34` FOREIGN KEY (`candidate_id`) REFERENCES `candidates_candidate` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=591098 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Can anyone guide me how can I catch the issue with this table ?

Comment: What would you say is too long?

Comment: @P.Salmon it just runs and runs until we manually kill it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` without any filtering (`WHERE`) must scan the entire table or an index.  This takes time.

Do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see how it is handled.  I think it will use your `UNIQUE(candidate_id)`.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Assuming that `candidate_id` is `INT` or `BIGINT`, the query can't be run much faster.

Why do you need to count the number of rows.  Would an *estimate* be "good enough"?  If so, see `SHOW TABLE STATUS` or the equivalent query in `information_schema`.

If the count from midnight this morning would be "good enough", then perform that and save it somewhere.

If you can't figure how to avoid timeout, see `wait_timeout`.  Caution; there are several flavors of it.

**With a Summary Table**

Build and maintain a table that keeps, say, the hourly counts of rows:

```
CREATE TABLE counts (
    hr MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ct SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(hr)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Initialize (one-time task):

```
INSERT INTO counts  (hr, ct)
    SELECT  FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(uploaded_on) / 3600),
            COUNT(*)
        FROM candidates_resume
        GROUP BY 1;
```

As a new row is inserted into `candidates_resume`:

```
INSERT INTO candidates_resume
    (hr, ct)
    VALUES
    (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(uploaded_on) / 3600), 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ct = ct + 1;
```

When wanting the count:

```
SELECT SUM(ct) FROM counts;
```

That gives the count up to the start of the current hour.  If you need the count up to the current second, add on a second query to count just the rows since the start of the hour.

(There are a few loose ends to fix.)

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: Yes, it is using `candidate_id` index for scanning table. I set timeout for all query after 30 min of starting and Also unfortunately `estimation` is not good enough

Comment: @DeepAdeshra - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and explain whether the data in the table comes and goes.  That is, are there actions that cause the `COUNT` to go down (eg deletions), or whether the number of rows only increases.  There is a technique that works ten times as fast, but it has limitations.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James. I've Updated the question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and In this table the data does not get deleted it only increases.

Comment: @DeepAdeshra - Sounds like your table is easy to build a Summary Table for.  How many records per hour are you getting currently?

Comment: it is largely varying but it could be around 1k-1.5k per hour @Rick James.

Comment: @DeepAdeshra - OK.  I asked because chopping the data by "1 hour" might have been too large or too small to let the Summary Table be efficient.  It is probably optimal.  If you traffic increases, you might switch to, say, 15-minute chunks.